# scala play2.5 how to pass global messages to template

Tags: scala, playframework, message, twirl

I have a play2.5 scala project and I want to pass a global message from the controller for example in case an error happened. How can I achieve this without using the form global message.

For example in the handleRegisterError method I would like to throw an global error message that would show on the top off the page.

What is the best approach to this?

I'm using twirl templates

```
 def registerUser = Action.async { implicit request =>

    RegisterForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.register(formWithErrors)))
      },
      formData => {
        registerUserService.registerUser(formData).map{ insertedId =>
          Ok(views.html.index(""))
        }
        .recover {
          case cause => handleRegisterError(cause)
        }
      })


  }

  def handleRegisterError(cause: Throwable)(implicit req: RequestHeader) : Result = {         
    cause match {
      case dae: DataAccessException =>
        //add an error message here
        BadRequest(views.html.register(RegisterForm.form))
      case _ =>
        BadRequest(views.html.register(RegisterForm.form))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `Redirect` with the message attached to `Flash` scope

```
Redirect(views.html.register(RegisterForm.form)).flashing("error" -> "Oops, you've got an error")
```

Add `RequestHeader` as a template parameter and render the error message if defined.

```
@(form: Form[RegisterForm])(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@request.flash.get("error").map { message =>
    <div>@message</div>
}
```

Comment: and what if I don't want to redirect?

Comment: Well, you can pass any object into the Twirl template

Comment: off course this is how I implemented it in the end, I was just wandering if something like this is already built in...tnx for the info anyway